# Equivalent definitions of strongly proximal action

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, group-actions

Consider the following fragment from the paper "C*-simplicity and the unique trace property for discrete groups" by Breuillard, Kalantar,
Kennedy and Ozawa:
[image]

I have two questions:

(1) What is the induced $G$-action on the space $\mathcal{P}(X)$?

My guess is the following: Given an action $\alpha: G \to \operatorname{Homeo}(X)$, is the induced action given by
$$(g\mu)(A) := \mu(\alpha_g^{-1}(A))$$ for $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $A \subseteq X$ a Borel subset. Is this correct?

(2) On other places, strongly proximal action is defined as follows:

An action $\alpha$ of $G$ on the compact space $X$ is strongly proximal if $\overline{G\mu}\cap X \ne \emptyset.$ Note that the closure is taken inside the weak$^*$-topology that $M(X)$ obtains from the duality $M(X) \cong S(C(X)) \subseteq C(X)^*$ and that $X$ is identified as a subset of $M(X)$ via $x \mapsto \delta_x$. In other words, the closure of each orbit under the induced action contains a dirac probability measure.

Are these two definitions of strongly proximal action equivalent? I can't seem to show either implication.

Comment: I'm sure you're right with (1), but don't know the answer to your question (2).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was already answered in the comments that you are right with (1).

For (2): yes, both definitions are equivalent. One direction is clear: applying the first definition to the pair $\mu,\delta_{x_0}$, one obtains that the closure of $G\mu$ intersects the closure of the set of Dirac measures, which is closed.

For the converse, use that Dirac measures are extreme points in $\mathcal{P}(X)$: if $\mu,\nu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, applying the second definition to $\frac 1 2 \mu + \frac 1 2 \nu$, one obtains the existence of a net $t_i \in G$ and $x \in X$ such that $\frac 1 2 t_i\mu + \frac 1 2 t_i \nu$ converges to $\delta_x$. Necessarily both $t_i \mu$ and $t_i\nu$ converge to $\delta_x$.